How to test node apps with threads, built with TypeScript?
I have server written on TypeScript, that build with rollup and run on node.
Currently i have a lot of tests as unit that import and test specific entities, as e2e that start server (with DB and other stuff) and then send requests with fetch as real client.
Now i want to move some work (mostly about cryptography and CPU bound data processing) in another thread. But i no have idea how to unit test functions who wrap whole logic about data processing.
For example, let's consider case with hash calculation in dedicated thread. How to write testable code?
I may introduce special file with code that will run in thread, then i will specify path to this file in main process, to start thread, and will message between thread and main process. Then i will wrap this code in main process to some function like calcHash(text: string): Promise<string>.
But i don't understand how i can test such code (I use Jest). With current approach, thread code is a .ts file that will be compiled, and placed beside server file, but i run tests in ts files with ts-jest so no .js file exists while testing.
It looks i do something wrong, so please correct me. Maybe it is not mandatory to write specific file for new thread?
As i understood, node no have option to run some function in thread like that:
const calcHashThread = () => {
  // code here will be executed in new thread
};

const calcHash = (text: string): Promise<string> => {
  const thread = spawnThread(calcHashThread);
  // message with thread here, and return result then
};


"how to create any code with typescript for nodejs that will use threads" is far too broad for a StackOverflow question. If you mean to ask specifically about Jest (not) transpiling source files for workers, please adjust your question (title, example, tags) and share your ts-jest setup.

@Bergi the topic is "How to test node apps with threads, built with TypeScript?", not "how to create any code with typescript for nodejs that will use threads".

You can use worker_threads to run something in a new thread. And use execArgv to allow importing .ts files:
worker.ts
import { parentPort } from 'worker_threads';
import crypto from 'crypto';

// Listen for messages from the parent thread
parentPort?.on('message', (text: string) => {
  // Calculate hash
  const hash = crypto.createHash('sha256').update(text).digest('hex');
  // Send the result back to the parent thread
  parentPort.postMessage(hash);
});

main.ts
import { Worker, WorkerOptions } from 'worker_threads';
import path from 'path';

// Function to calculate hash using a worker thread
const calcHash = (text: string): Promise<string> => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // Create a new worker thread
    const options: WorkerOptions = {
        //... 
    };
    const worker = new Worker(
        path.resolve(__dirname, 'worker.ts'),
        ...options,
        execArgv: /\.ts$/.test(resolvedPath) ?
            ["--require", "ts-node/register"] : undefined,
    );

    // Send the input text to the worker thread
    worker.postMessage(text);

    // Listen for messages from the worker
    worker.on('message', (hash: string) => {
      resolve(hash);
    });

    // Handle any errors that occur in the worker
    worker.on('error', (error: Error) => {
      reject(error);
    });

    // Handle when the worker exits
    worker.on('exit', (code: number) => {
      if (code !== 0) {
        reject(new Error(`Worker stopped with exit code ${code}`));
      }
    });
  });
};

// Example usage
calcHash('Hello, world!')
  .then((hash) => {
    console.log('Hash:', hash);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error('Error:', error);
  });

You can also make sure that execArgv is only used in the dev and test environments.
For the test itself you can write a simple unit test that mocks crypto.createHash module, invokes calcHash and asserts the return.

Create a separate file for your worker logic. For example, hashWorker.ts might look like this
// hashWorker.ts
import { parentPort } from 'worker_threads';
import crypto from 'crypto';

parentPort?.on('message', (text: string) => {
  const hash = crypto.createHash('sha256').update(text).digest('hex');
  parentPort?.postMessage(hash);
});

In your main code, use the Worker class to handle threading:
import { Worker } from 'worker_threads';
import path from 'path';

const runWorker = (text: string): Promise<string> => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const worker = new Worker(path.resolve(__dirname, 'hashWorker.ts'));
    
    worker.postMessage(text);
    
    worker.on('message', (hash: string) => {
      resolve(hash);
    });
    
    worker.on('error', reject);
    worker.on('exit', (code) => {
      if (code !== 0) {
        reject(new Error(`Worker stopped with exit code ${code}`));
      }
    });
  });
};

export default runWorker;

Use Jest to test the interactions. For testing the runWorker function, you can use mocks to simulate the worker behavior.
    // hashService.test.ts
import { Worker } from 'worker_threads';
import runWorker from './hashService';

jest.mock('worker_threads', () => {
  const originalModule = jest.requireActual('worker_threads');
  return {
    ...originalModule,
    Worker: jest.fn().mockImplementation((scriptPath) => {
      const worker = {
        postMessage: jest.fn(),
        on: jest.fn((event, callback) => {
          if (event === 'message') {
            // Simulate the worker sending a message back
            setImmediate(() => callback('fakehash'));
          }
        }),
      };
      return worker as any;
    }),
  };
});

describe('runWorker', () => {
  it('should return the hash calculated by the worker', async () => {
    const result = await runWorker('test');
    expect(result).toBe('fakehash');
  });
});


This code does not test interaction between main thread and code in in hashWorker.ts. How we can solve this problem?

How do you expect node.js to handle the TypeScript file with new Worker(path.resolve(__dirname, 'hashWorker.ts'))?
